# What does it take to put an ie tab to sleep?

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs

I have noticed that ie tends to put the thread for a tab to sleep after long periods of inactivity. I have some questions related to this

1>After how much time does the thread for the tab sleep?

2>Will the thread sleep even if there are continuous ajax calls?

3>Does the time after which the thread sleep, have anything to do with user specific settings on the browser or computer?

A link to an article that deals with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing is inactive processess swapped out.  This isn't an IE feature, but an OS feature.  IE just uses multiple processess for hosting tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard question ;-) I did not find anything about tab thread suspension. But I hope this links will help you a bit:

- [IE7 Tabbed Browsing Implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/05/26/422103.aspx)
- [Opening a New Tab may launch a New Process with Internet Explorer 8.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx)